# How would I go about getting the user input from a popup that contains a text input in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, react

I want to make a list of places I'd like to visit. When I click on the map a marker is placed and a popup appears above the marker. The popup contains a text input field and a submit button to save whatever the user inputs. 
I would like to know how to get the user input when submitting the information. 
this may seem trivial, but i'm at a loss on how to do this in mapbox gl js.

I Intend to use this in a React app at a later stage to save the info to the local state of a component.

Here's a simple gist just to give you a context:

https://gist.github.com/Aknotofknots/364bf05fa763614c2116e31fe400e95b